# Asterisk 16.4 pjsip trunk registration

Tags: asterisk

I'm not an asterisk expert, and I'm stuck at this moment.

I'm trying to setup an asterisk box with realtime. Most work, and my endpoints are able to make calls between each other. But I need to setup a SIP trunk to a VOIP provider, and I'm not sure how to do it, because what I've done does not work.

1. The first problem is that my registration does not load. From what I understood the sorcery.conf file needs to be setup for the different objects. I determined that the type basically maps to the type in `pjsip.conf`, So I've setup the information in there. Like I said, the aors, endpoint and auth of my trunk reflects and is loaded, but I can't seem to get the registration.

I've tried setting up the registration (and identity) in pjsip.conf, as well as in the mysql db, but when i run `pjsip show registrations`, no objects are found. I thought that maybe it is because `sorcery.conf` does not map the table, but when I add `registration=realtime,ps_registrations` to the sorcery.conf, pjsip does not start at all

This is my current sorcery.conf setup. I've included the commented lines for incase

```
[res_pjsip]
endpoint=realtime,ps_endpoints
auth=realtime,ps_auths
aor=realtime,ps_aors
domain_alias=realtime,ps_domain_aliases
;registration=realtime,ps_registrations

[res_pjsip_endpoint_identifier_ip]
identify=realtime,ps_endpoint_id_ips

;[res_pjsip_outbound_publish]
;outbound-publish=realtime,ps_outbound_publishes

;[res_pjsip_pubsub]
;inbound-publication=realtime,ps_inbound_publications

;[res_pjsip_publish_asterisk]
;asterisk-publication=realtime,ps_asterisk_publications
```

I have same settings in pjsip.conf as well

```
[mtntrunk]
type=registration
outbound_auth=mtntrunk_auth
server_uri=sip:<ip address of provider>
client_uri=sip:<number>@<ip address of provider>
retry_interval=60
;forbidden_retry_interval=600
;expiration=3600
;line=yes
endpoint=mtntrunk
```

Endpoint `mtntrunk` does show when I run commands `pjsip show endpoints`

If there is more info that you want please ask.

Is there something that I missing? Is my configuration incorrect? Should I configure config file as well as realtime config to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `extconfig.conf` a line has to be added

```
ps_registrations = odbc,asterisk
```

and in `sorcery.conf` you can then add (or uncomment the block)

```
[res_pjsip_outbound_registration]
registration=realtime,ps_registrations
```

You also have to add the identify into table `ps_endpoint_id_ips`

Then the configurations can be removed from `pjsip.conf`.
In order for your transport (that is probably still in `pjsip.conf`) to load, you need to add into `pjsip.conf` the following as well

```
transport=config,pjsip.conf,criteria=type=transport
```

or if you do it realtime, configure with your realtime table name, but according to docs it is not recommended.